# Simple Background Color in Three.js/WebGL Globe

Tags: three.js

I'm implementing this [WebGL Globe Chrome Experiments](https://www.chromeexperiments.com/globe) on my page and simply need to change the background color.

The standard is black, but [this example](http://sentdex.com/global-sentiment-analysis/) managed to have a nice either transparent or white background. Ideally, I'd really prefer transparent, but white works too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want white on the background then use

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff );
```

if you want transparent then use

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );
renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 ); // the second parameter is opacity
```